# Swift Struct compiler error "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, initialization, swiftui

According to [The Swift Programming Language Book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)...

> Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types
>   Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they don’t define any of their own custom initializers. Unlike a default initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer even if it has stored properties that don’t have default values.

However, I'm getting a "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" error if I try to compile while relying on this automatic memberwise initializer.

Even more frustrating, sometimes if I clean the build folder it will compile, then a few builds later the error will be back. I'm using XCode Version 11.4 beta (11N111s).

```
struct OpenShoppingListPage: View {

    @Binding var tabSelection: Int
    @ObservedObject var storesData: StoresData
    @ObservedObject var shoppingListData: ShoppingListData

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(storesData.openShoppingLists) { eachLedger in
                Button(action: {
                    self.shoppingListData.dataStack.currentReceipt = eachLedger
                    self.shoppingListData.refreshSections()
                    self.tabSelection = 0
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(eachLedger.dateLedger.shortDate())—\(eachLedger.myStore!.longName)")
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Open Shopping Lists")
    }
}
```

I can fix this by manually typing an init() as shown below. However, that's boilerplate that I was hoping to avoid by using Swift Struct. Is anyone else seeing this problem with recent XCode builds?

```
init(tabSelection: Binding<Int>, storesData: StoresData, shoppingListData: ShoppingListData) {
    self._tabSelection = tabSelection
    self.storesData = storesData
    self.shoppingListData = shoppingListData
}
```

I have submitted feedback to Apple, but am hoping Stack Overflow can provide faster feedback.

Comment: There is already released Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146).

Comment: If you need this memberwise initializer to be available outside of the current access level (higher than `internal`), you have to type it out unfortunately.